# Timestamped messages in Akka

Tags: time, akka

I have an actor that emits messages to other actors. These messages contain a timestamp that comes from System.currentTimeMillis and therefore are based on the time of the JVM the emitting actor resides in.

If a remote actor on another node - with a time not synchronized to the emitting actor - uses this timestamp for calculating e.g. a duration based on its System.currentTimeMillis, then the results are possibly not correct.

Are there helpers available in Akka to tackle such time-related problems like and internal time to an ActorSystem that is synchronized with each actor, no matter if it's local or remote?

Comment: Not really, it is the job of the Operating System and its supporting services to provide proper time synchronization.

Comment: Ok, I just thought that maybe Akka provides something like that. Thanks.